# Exit Popup With Respone Redirect

Tags: php, javascript, html, redirect, response

I have a requirement to show an Exit Popup on one of our processing pages. I am showing the exit popup by registering a client side javascript like

```
window.onbeforeunload = ShowExitPopUp();
```

The popup executes fine if you close the window, or try to type in a different URL. However the issue is that my processing page is also performing a "Response.Redirect" on the server side once the process completes. When response.redirect happens the exitpopup also shows up. Is there a way to have the exit popup not show up in that case?

this is the code below which i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
    function (response) {
        window.location = "http://domain.com";
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('comments.remove',
    function (response) {
        window.location = "http://domain.com";
    });   
};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
//]]>
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
var ShowExitPopup = true;
function ExitPage()
{
if (ShowExitPopup) 
{ 
ShowExitPopup = false;
location.href = "http://www.YOURURL.com/destination";
return '****************************************\n\YOUR HEADLINE\n\n YOUR TEXT1 \n\n  YOUR TEXT "\n\n                                                                                                     | |\n                                                                                                     | |\n                                                                                                    V V\n                                                      96+                                                v\n  ********************************************************\n';
}
} 
</script>
```

Comment: if I was implementing then I just add document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=Panel.ClientID %>').style.display == "") {
$find("<%= Popup.ClientID %>").hide();
document.getElementById("<%= btncloseAcc.ClientID %>").click();
}
```

try this..........